# Parsing author name, title, journal from unstructured references

Tags: parsing

I have a list of references. I'm trying to parse author name, title, journal name,volume no etc. All reference entries are not uniform. Some contain only title and  multiple author names, some contain only title etc. How to do i go about parsing this and storing information in relevant columns? Few examples of the reference entries are as shown below.

- Neufeld et al., ?Vascular endothelial growth factor (VEGF) and its receptors,?The FASEB Journal, vol. 13, pp. 9-22 (1999).
- PCT ?International Search Report and Written Opinion? for International Application No. PCT/US08/60740, mailed , Aug. 19, 2008; 7 pages.
- Wirth, et al. Interactions between DNA and mono-, bis-, tris-, tetrakis-, and hexakis(aminoacridines). A linear and circular dichroism, electric orientation relaxation, viscometry, and equilibrium study. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1988; 110 (3):932-939.
- Buadu LD, Murakami, J, Murayama S., et al., ?Breast Lesions: Correlation of Contrast Medium Enhancement Patterns on MR Images with Histophathological Findings and Tumor Angiogenesis,? Radiology 1996, 200:639-649.
- Bers ?Excitation Contraction Coupling and Cardiac Contractile Force?, Internal Medicine, 237(2): 17, 1991, Abstract.
- Abella, J., Vera, X., Gonzalez, A., ?Penelope: The NBTI-Aware Processor?, MICRO 2007, pp. 85-96.
- JP Office Action dtd Dec. 2, 2010, JP Appln. 2008-273888, partial English translation.
- Maruyama, H., et al., ?Id-1 and Id-2 are Overexpressed in Pancreatic Cancer and in Dysplastic Lesions in Chronic Pancreatitis,?American Journal of Pathology?155(3):815-822 (1999).
- Attachment 2, High Speed Data RLP Lucent Technologies, Version 0.1, Jan. 16, 1997.
- Diddens, Heyke et al. ?Patterns of Cross-Resistance to the Antigolate Drugs Trimetrexate, Metoprine, Homofolate, and CB3717 in Human Lymphoma and Osteosarcoma Cells Resistant to Methotrexate.? Cancer Research, Nov. 1983, pp. 5286-5292, vol. 43.
- Installation drawings having drawing No. 1069965, dated Aug. 14, 1999 (3 pages).
- Means et al., Chemical modifications of proteins: history and applications, Bioconjugate Chem., 1:2-12 (1990).
- Bock, ?Natural History of Severe Reactions to Foods in Young Children,?J. Pediatr. 107: 676-680, 1985.
- Chankhunthod, Anawat, et al., ?A Hierarachical Internet Object Cache,? in Proceedings of the USENIX 1996 Annual Technical Conference; San Diego, CA., (Jan. 1996), pp. 153-163.

Comment: Have you started on a solution yet?

Comment: No, I'm new to this area. I have no idea how to go about

Comment: please be elaborate about the technology you use, the language you use, the database or is it a text file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll be more likely to get help if you can show something that you've tried and is not working, than vague 'how do I' type questions.

Comment: It's data stored in tsv file. I want to parse it and store it to mysql database. I'm not sure which technology to use